# Moving ball inside a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const velocitySlider = document.getElementById('velocityRange');
const angleSlider = document.getElementById('angleRange');
let velocityOutput = document.getElementById('velocityValue');
let angleOutput = document.getElementById('angleValue');

angleOutput.innerHTML = angleSlider.value; // Display the default slider value
velocityOutput.innerHTML = velocitySlider.value;
// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
angleSlider.oninput = function() {
  angleOutput.innerHTML = this.value;
};
velocitySlider.oninput = function() {
  velocityOutput.innerHTML = this.value;
};

function handleReset() {
  event.preventDefault();
  angleSlider.value = 45;
  angleOutput.innerHTML = angleSlider.value;
  velocitySlider.value = 25;
  velocityOutput.innerHTML = velocitySlider.value;
}

var ball = { position: { x: 0, y: canvas.height } };
var T = 0;
var oldTimeStamp = 0;
var secondsPassed = 0;
var animationSpeed = 500;
var g = 0.0005;

function handleSubmit() {
  // ️ prevent page refresh
  event.preventDefault();
  var initialVelocity = velocitySlider.value;
  var initialAngle = angleSlider.value;
  animate();
  console.log('animate');
}

function animate(timeStamp) {
  secondsPassed = (timeStamp - oldTimeStamp) / 1000.0;
  oldTimeStamp = timeStamp;
  update();
  draw();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function update() {
  T += animationSpeed * secondsPassed;
}

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(20 + T, 20 + T, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

if you can help me moving the ball in the canvas , I am trying to simulate projectile motion

I take the angle & velocity from range input and I want to handle the submit function to call the animation after the user hit the button

[image]

Comment: You have many variables that you are just not using ... g, ball, initialVelocity, initialAngle ... Does not look like you tried anything at all

Comment: replacing the ball with rocket will not make it move.

Comment: Add that code to your question not here in the comments ... also you should reduce your code to a working snippet, look at what I did below

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you have not done anything...
I'm just going to give you a small push to show movement on the X axis

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var ball = { x: 10, y: canvas.height-10, v: 25, a: 45 } 
var animationSpeed = 500;
var g = 0.0005;

function animate(time) {
  ball.x = ball.v * time / animationSpeed
  
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(ball.x, ball.y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=600 ></canvas>
```

Projectile motion is not trivial, but all the formulas are well documented, you can read more here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion